# Could not find the main class, program will exit

Tags: java, jar

I made an executable jar with the command prompt in Windows 7 using the

```
jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

which created the .jar file. But when I attempt to open it, I get a pop-up window that says

```
Could not find the main class: <ClassName>. Program will exit.
```

Yet, when I use

```
java -jar jarName.jar
```

in the command prompt, it works fine. What's the deal? I want to be able to just double-click it.

Comment: Show us the content of manifest file

Comment: I can't tell from what little you've explained, but in general if your main class is "com.Main", then Main.class needs to exist inside of a "com" folder within the jar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why it's failed to load main-class manifest attribute from jar-file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-its-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-jar-file)

Comment: Well, my manifest file just contains the line "Main-Class: NatTimer" because my class's name is NatTimer... When I extracted the one out of the jar, it had 2 extra lines above it; "Manifest-Version: 1.0" and "Created-By: 1.7.0 (Oracle Corporation)" But that probably isn't the problem, right?

Now, when I made the jar, I didn't have any package statement in the code, nor was it in any sort of special folder for jarring. ...That's the problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ha, I found what the problem was. I made my program using jdk1.7, but I had jre6 installed. I went and upgraded to jre7, and now it works fine :)

The

```
java -jar jarname.jar
```

line was working in the command prompt because my java path was set to the jdk folder.

Comment: I had the same problem, but i had already jre7 installed, but since my application was **32bit** i had to download and install _jre7-i586(x86)_ too. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `JDK 1.6` or higher then you can override the manifest attribute via `e` flag of `Jar` tool. (Read - [Setting an Entry Point with the JAR Tool)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

Example:

```
package pack;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String []args)  
   {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Compile and run Jar tool,

```
c:\>jar cfe app.jar pack.Test pack/Test.class
```

Invoke app

```
c:>java -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

The Manifest text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. What I did is I right clicked the project->properties and from "Select/Binary Format" combo box, I selected JDK 6. Then I did clean and built and now when I click the Jar, It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you build the source files with lower version of Java (example Java1.5) and trying to run that program/application with higher version of Java (example java 1.6) you will get this problem.
for better explanation see this link. [click here](http://javabestpractice.blogspot.ie/2015/04/could-not-find-main-class-program-will.html)

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue in opening JMeter 4.0. I fixed as below.

I have JRE 7 installed in Program Files (x86) folder and JDK 8 installed in Program files folder. So I just uninstalled JRE7 from machine. I just kept latest version of JDK. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the jar and compare the contents of the manifest inside the jar with your external manifest.txt. It is quite possible that you will locate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check out doing  this way (works on my machine):

**let the file be x.java**

1. compile the file javac x.java
2. jar cfe k.jar x x.class  //k.jar is jar file
3. java -jar k.jar