# Cannot run .jar files

Tags: java, jar

I switched from Java JDK (and JRE) 7 to 6u45. For some reason, I can not run .jar files anymore. I changed the default program to run the .jar files to the new JDK's *javaw.exe* - but it doesn't work. Moreover, I tried using the new JRE's *javaw.exe* too - it doesn't work. In both cases I'm getting this error:

> "Could not find the main class: Program will exit.
>   C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\myJar.jar"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617807/could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run the JAR from a command line using `java.exe`?

Comment: I get no error when using the command prompt. I wrote it in Java 7, downgraded to Java 6, and reinstalled Eclipse and re-wrote it in Java 6. I don't know why the jar would't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompile it, with option `-target 1.6`, than you will be able to run on 6 too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not running java with the -jar argument.

try:

```
java.exe -jar C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\myJar.jar
```

Comment: It works fine when using it in the command prompt, I just can't use it by clicking on the file itself.