# Console Input error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, io

I have tried code:

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Default
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Console console = System.console();
        String testing = console.readLine("Enter Name: ");
        System.out.println("Entered Name: "+ testing);
    }
}
```

goes to exception with following error: 

`Source not found. NullPointerException`

I am using Eclipse Juno EE for debugging .. !

And the reference link for above written code is [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79)

Comment: Is the error thrown at compile time or run time?

Comment: @MatthewCoster, run time!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide) question will help then.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Comment: possible duplicate of [Masking password input from the console : Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running your program from an ide as `console.readLine` returns `null` when used from an IDE.

[For more details refer to this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

If you run it from command line you will not get this error.

Comment: In my case in Linux console when i run the script from run.sh i got `NullPointerException` after removing `"&"` from end of my script and remove `nohup` from the beginning the error gone away.
good-luck

Answer (score 3):

`System.console()` returns null if there is no console.

You can work round this either by [adding a layer of indirection to your code](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html) or by running the code in an external console and [attaching a remote debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide).

Comment: Exactly - and, this is true when running from within Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Comment: I tried the same in netbeans, `System.console()` returns null even here. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

That is because, IDE is not using console !

Go to cmd.exe

type `cd <bin path>` hit enter..

now type `java <classname>` hit enter

It works!

Comment: Well, you're right. It works from windows console. But the problem here is, OP is using Eclipse IDE. And Eclipse IDE does not have a `System.console()`. It's a known bug: - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Comment: @RohitJain, I said the same thing his IDE doesn't use console. But you can run any java compiled code from command prompt. That's the beauty of Java!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class ConsoleExTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Console c = System.console();
        String uname = c.readLine("User Name:");
        char[] pwd = c.readPassword("Password:");
        String upwd = new String(pwd);
        if (uname.equals("chenna") && upwd.equals("chenna")) {
            System.out.println("User is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("User is not valid");
        }
    }

}
```

Note:

`System.console();` return null so we will get

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem has already been mentioned in other answers, but I would like to add one possible solution.

There is a library that can be used as a replacement for `java.io.Console` that mitigates the problem: https://codeberg.org/marc.nause/console-with-fallback