# How to hide input from display?

Tags: java

How do I prevent input from being visible on the display console in Java? I, for instance, want to take some private info as input from the user, but don't want to make it visible to the people around him.

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Console class and use the readPassword() method. When user enters data, it will be replaced with asterisks.