# How to hide input in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, password-protection

This question, [Masking password input from the console : Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java[1]), addresses using the `Console` class to hide input as asterisks.  How can this be done in a Swing GUI, where input is entered into a `JTextArea`, rather than the console?

Comment: Use this? `JPasswordField` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html

Comment: @3kings post as answer...

Comment: @djechlin as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use this Swing component instead.

`JPasswordField`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html