# Hide Password Input On Console Window

Tags: java, passwords, hidden

When typing in my password to the console window it is visible, is there anyway this can be changed so that it can't be visible? Here is my code:

```
    String user, pass, host;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type userid, password, hostname or ipaddress: ");
    user = sc.next();
    pass = sc.next();
    host = sc.next();
    System.out.println(user + " " + pass + " " + host);
    Methods md = new Methods();
    md.createTable(user, pass, host);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Masking password input from the console : Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--) `readPassword()` method:

```
 char[] passwd = System.console().readPassword("[%s]", "Password:");
```