# How to convet a string in java to its dotted form?

Tags: java

I want to design a SIMPLE Java progeam to input a string (password) in its dotted form and display the same in its un-dotted form. 
Sample input: *****       (entered 12345)
Sample output: 12345

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a GUI system, You would want to use a `PasswordField` in JavaFX or `JPasswordField` in Swing.

This will allow you to type in the box and have the "Dotted" input.

You can then call `.getText()`(returns a `String`) for the `PasswordField`, or call `.getPassword()` for the `JPasswordField` (returns a `char[]`) to get the raw text values.

Alternatively, if you are using console, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138411/masking-password-input-from-the-console-java) for an answer

Comment: I&#39;m using blueJ. After getting the string in dots, will the same have the external interface of the dots or the internal interface too?

Comment: @user9836598 On the User interface, the values of the password field will remain dotted, but you can use the "non-dotted" values within your program as plain text(no dots).