# Failed to load Main-class Manifest Attribute

Tags: java, jar, jvm, executable-jar, jvm-crash

I am getting following error while executing compiled jar file. I have re installed my java but my problem is not solved yet.

> ```
> Failed to load Main-class Manifest Attribute from
> D:\Tools\Lodable_Creation\dist\Lodable_Creation.jar
> ```

Currently by `MANIFEST.MF` file looks like.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.6.0-b105 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: main
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 IDE.

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-its-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-jar-file

Comment: Well what does your manifest look like? Have you *tried* to specify a Main-class attribute?

Comment: Please open your JAR with some tool like winzip/7zip and paste `META-INF/Manifest.mf` contents in the question

Comment: Also, why is there a space before the jar name?

Comment: please use first capital letter in class names (`Main`) and lowercase for methods (`main()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a package for your class. Make sure your class looks something like this (notice the package and the public class):

```
package com.foo;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

After which you can specify `Main-Class` as so:

```
Main-Class: com.foo.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

As adarshr suggested, JVM is not able to find the class because it requires the fully-qualified name in the Main-Class attribute of Manifest file.

Actually, it is not really necessary to specify the main file. You can just give your JAR file as your classpath, and give the fully-qualified name of the class to run it using java.

Say your JAR is myJar.jar and the fully-qualified main file is com.user.Main. Then from the command line, go to the directory which has your JAR File and give :-

```
java -classpath myJar.jar com.user.Main
```

And this will run the Main class. You would also need to give the classes (or JARs) in the classpath which are used (imported) in your Main class.

See [this](http://samindaw.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/specifying-the-main-class-to-run-in-a-jar-file-from-command-line/) link for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when I have developed projects with a JDK(1.7 in my case) and the installed JRE was an older version(1.6). Try to update your JRE or change the JDK used, if possible, to match your JRE version.