# Why do i get an error while creating a jar file out of my code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String username = "xxx.xxxx@xxx.com";
        final String password = "xxxo@xxxx";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "webmxzz.xxxxxxx.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxx.x@xxxx.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("xxxx.x@xxxx.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear User,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

While writing a code to send an email across the network i found this code.The jars i use are : `javaee-api-5.jar`, `activation.jar` and `mail.jar`

I compile the code and run it in eclipse.It works fine and sends a mail to the desired mail id but the problem occurs when i try to make a jar file out of it by exporting the jar file i get the warning : Jar exported .Finished with warnings.

The error i get is :

```
Could not find the main class: (class). Program will exit.
```

What could be the possible reason? Kindly help me find the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-its-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-jar-file

Comment: Whenever i compile the code i always get MailSender$1.class in the bin apart from the MailSender.class

Comment: / Compiled from MailSender.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
class MailSender$1 extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
  
  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  MailSender$1();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokespecial javax.mail.Authenticator() [8]
    4  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 31]
        [pc: 4, line: 1]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: new MailSender(){}
  
  // Method descriptor #15 ()Ljavax/mail/PasswordAuthentication;
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 1
  protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication

Comment: getPasswordAuthentication();
     0  new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication [16]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "xxx@xxx.com"> [18]
     6  ldc <String "xxx@xxx"> [20]
     8  invokespecial javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [22]
    11  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 33]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 12] local: this index: 0 type: new MailSender(){}

  Inner classes:
    [inner class info: #1 MailSender$1, outer class info: #0
     inner name: #0, accessflags: 0 default]

Comment: Enclosing Method: #28  #30 MailSender.main([Ljava/lang/String;)

Comment: I have copy pasted the contents of the MailSender$1 file being created

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a manifest file should be created. This file contains one-line text file with a "Main-Class" e.x: Main-Class: Your Main class

Or you can use eclipse to do that: [Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)