# Exporting a jar using Eclipse and then running it

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have five .java files in a certain Eclipse project in the `src` folder. The project folder has  (apart from the `bin`, `lib` and `src` folders), the `help` file and the `properties` file along with certain input files.

I need to create a `.jar` file with the java files, and make it executable from the command line, along with the properties file as a parameter.

For example :

`java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar -info file.properties`

I used Eclipse to export the project as a `.jar` file, into the `bin` folder.

I copied all the input files, the `properties` file and the `help` file into the `dist` folder and ran the command.

I got an error saying

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from jar
```

I then checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-has-it-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-a-jar-file) answer and did the needful (created the manifest file with a line) and the ran

`jar cfm <jar-file-name>.jar <manifest-file-name> ./bin/*.class`

It didn't work, and threw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added the Main class by choosing 'Next' instead of 'Finish' while exporting the .jar. Now, while executing it, it threw a "ClassNotFoundException" for the  mysql connector jar. Even though, it is included in the lib folder which had been added while making the jar.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

**Second EDIT**

Relevant outputs.

`java -cp ./lib/* -jar <non-runnable-jar>.jar -info info.properties`

where `./lib/` has all the dependent jars.

It gave this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at polygonprobability.Model.readTestingData(Model.java:178)
    at polygonprobability.Model.<init>(Model.java:136)
    at polygonprobability.Info.getModel(Main.java:290)
    at polygonprobability.Main.loadInfo(Main.java:138)
    at polygonprobability.Main.operInfo(Main.java:61)
    at polygonprobability.Main.distribute(Main.java:170)
    at polygonprobability.Main.parse(Main.java:81)
    at polygonprobability.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at polygonprobability.DatabaseConnect.authorizeSQL(DatabaseConnect.java:50)
    at polygonprobability.Model.readTestingData(Model.java:157)
    ... 7 more
```

For

`java -cp /lib* -jar <non-runnable>.jar <packagename>.Main -info info.properties`

It gave this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /lib64
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .lib64
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: /lib64. Program will exit.
```

Comment: eclipse can create a simple jar and a runnable jar. did you export a runnable jar?

Comment: Check my edit. :) And it's simple (not runnable jar)

Comment: @wrahool: Do you have dependencies over other jars apart from the jar you are creating?

Comment: @JtheRocker yes. They are in the lib folder, which I've selected while creating the Jar.

Comment: And -info and file.properties are you arguments?

Comment: The only thing separating a "simple jar" from a "runnable jar" is the presence of a Class-Path line in MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps -

1. Export a **non-runnable** jar *without* the Main class included (skip the next part)
2. Then do this `java -cp /path/to/lib/*:yourjar.jar pkg.MainClass -info file.properties`

**/path/to/lib/*** = path to all your dependent jars.

Comment: @wrahool: Please, tell me the steps you did?

Comment: No, Ubuntu.

I created a non-runnable jar and put it in the `dist` folder.

I put the dependent jars in the `lib` folder.

Comment: I see you used this: java -cp /lib* -jar <non-runnable>.jar <packagename>.Main -info info.properties but I suggested this:
java -cp /path/to/lib/*:<non-runnable>.jar <packagename>.MainClass -info file.properties

Comment: My bad, I ran

`java -cp ./lib/* -jar <non-runnable>.jar <packagename>.Main -info info.properties`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34609/discussion-between-wrahool-and-jtherocker)

Answer (score 0):

The command line to run a jar should be

```
java -jar myJar.jar your.package.ClasswithMainMethod
```

If this is provided errors please include them.

I believe you might specifically want

```
java -jar myJar.jar your.package.ClasswithMainMethod args
```

And the best way I find to run the program is from inside your project file one step above the dist folder so you would actually run

```
java -jar ./dist/myJar.jar your.package.ClasswithMainMethod args
```

That way when you rebuild Eclipse doesn't complain that it can't delete the dist folder

Lastly if you for some reason have moved your lib path try the following

```
java -cp /path/to/lib/*:myJar.jar your.package.ClasswithMainMethod args
```

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work, because the command expects a -info <filename> as arguments.

Comment: This is how you run a jar and fix your error of not declaring a main class. Please try it and report back errors. You shouldn't have to moe anything. Everything you need should be found in your dist folder including your lib folder.