# How to run a jar file in a linux commandline

Tags: java

How to set the classpath to the current directory and also run the jar file named `load.jar` present in the current directory by providing the argument as `load=2` from a linux command line.

I did try to run the jar as follows but its executing classes from some other directory.

```
java -cp ./load.jar:$CLASSPATH load.Start load=2
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? I also suggest to read the command page of `java`.

Comment: read the `jar` command man page? You mean the `java` command man page, right? An RTFM response should point to the right FM.

Answer (score 139):

Running a from class inside your JAR file `load.jar` is possible via

```
java -jar load.jar
```

When doing so, you have to define the application entry point. Usually this is done by providing a manifest file that contains the `Main-Class` tag. For documentation and examples have a look at this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). 
The argument `load=2` can be supplied like in a normal Java applications:

```
java -jar load.jar load=2
```

Having also the current directory contained in the classpath, required to also make use of the `Class-Path` tag. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
load.jar`. How can I solve this error.

Comment: Your jar missed the Manifest file. Have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-has-it-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-a-jar-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-has-it-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-a-jar-file)

Comment: I ket the manifest.txt in the same directory where my classes are and it had the value `Main-Class: load.sampLoad` and I issed the command `jar cfm load.jar manifest.txt *` and the jar file is created with an additional directory `Meta-INF` with the filename `MANIFEST.MF` but it does not have the line which I had in manifest.txt but has only the java version used to compile. What went wrong here.

Comment: i was stuck in this command for a whole day, only to realize that i haven't put the - sign before jar when executing this command :/

Answer (score 21):

For example to execute from terminal (Ubuntu Linux) or even (Windows console) a java file called filex.jar use this command:

`java -jar filex.jar`

The file will execute in terminal.

Answer (score 9):

Under linux there's a package called `binfmt-support` that allows you to run directly your jar without typing `java -jar`:

```
sudo apt-get install binfmt-support
chmod u+x my-jar.jar
./my-jar.jar # there you go!
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: "invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error"

Comment: @A.Kojen Try `sudo apt-get install jarwrapper`, which is a package on top of `binfmt-support`.  At least for me, the default for `binfmt-support` was `jexec` -- which I think is OpenJDK's -- and that couldn't run my .jar for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For OpenSuse Linux, One can simply install the java-binfmt package in the zypper repository as shown below:

```
sudo zypper in java-binfmt-misc
chmod 755 file.jar
./file.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to utilize an additional flag- console to get it up and running:

```
java -jar jarfilename.jar -console
```

The console flag was needed to run the file in shell and do instructions needed for setup like installation path and accept terms and conditions.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo -sH
java -jar filename.jar
```

Keep in mind to never run executable file in as root.

Answer (score -5):

copy your file in linux Java directory

```
cp yourfile.jar /java/bin
```

open the directory

```
cd /java/bin
```

and execute your file

`./java -jar yourfile.jar`

or all in one try this command:

`/java/bin/java -jar jarfilefolder/jarfile.jar`