# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext

Tags: java, web-services, jar, mainclass, ws-client

I am trying to follow this [Apache CXF – JAX-WS – Simple Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/apache-cxf-jax-ws-simple-tutorial.html) but  building the **downloaded** sample (out of the box!) creates a client that upon invocation refuses to run, issuing this error:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
>   SampleWSCxfClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I searched to find out more about this problem and found out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591548/3154666) which prompted me to hack SampleWSCxfClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar by opening it using `7-zip` and adding into a file name `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` the following line:

```
Main-Class: com.areyes.sample.client.SampleWSClient
```

I figured out that main class by simply looking at the only Java file in the project:

```
package com.areyes.sample.client;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.sample.service.SampleWebService;

public class SampleWSClient {


    public SampleWSClient() {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/beans.xml");
        classPathXmlAppContext.start();

        SampleWebService sampleWebService = (SampleWebService)classPathXmlAppContext.getBean("client");

        System.out.println(sampleWebService.getDataFromWebService().getName());
        System.out.println(sampleWebService.getDataFromWebService().getDescription());
        System.out.println(sampleWebService.getDataFromWebService().getAge());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SampleWSClient();
    }
}
```

I then tried to invoke SampleWSCxfClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar again, but this time it fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.areyes.sample.client.SampleWSClient. Program will exit.
```

How do I make this sample work?

---

For your convenience, the entire sample package ZIP can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1737239/SampleWSCxf.zip).

Comment: Just to check: you're using Maven to build it, right?

Comment: @JoeRinehart Yes, I do. and the `pom.xml` already contains the `spring-context` dependency. You can actually see the entire project package verbatim [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1737239/SampleWSCxf.zip). Why a complete tutorial package doesn't work out-of-the-box is beyond me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's what kind of threw me - I downloaded it and it's right there in the POM. How are you trying to run it / what's creating a classpath to include everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once came across a similar problem and after being unable to decipher the magic of running "a jar with many dependencies" from the command line, I worked around it by running it through Maven.

Try this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.areyes.sample.client.SampleWSClient
```

Answer (score 0):

for maven based projects, please follow the below link to create runnable jar. For maven based project, making jar using export->jar option doesnt work. It work for me successfully.

[CREATING RUNNABLE JAR for maven based eclipse project](http://www.coderanch.com/t/565540/vc/creating-runnable-jar-Eclipse-Maven)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it got fixed after I updated the classpathPrefix in my pom.xml. Support_lib/ .

After you build the project using maven, the 'target' folder had this Support_lib/ dir with all the spring jar files in it. so I used this dir name in the classpathPrefix and it worked.